# ANTLR4TS Java How to get Method Parameter types?

Tags: antlr4

I need to get the parameters types of a method in a java file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          myMethod();
}
```

Like in this code I wanna to get just String[] without anything infront or behind it.
I use ANTLR4TS with the Java9Parser file distributed by them. Maybe somebody here knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, its the enterFormalParameter.

```
enterFormalParameter (ctx: FormalParameterContext){ 
     ctx.getChild(0).text; 
}
```

Thats the way to get it.